# jQuery autocomplete script not resolving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to embed an example jQuery into my static webpage which should autocomplete itself. Since this is the first time I am working on front end so not sure where I am getting it wrong.

**For some reason the autocomplete is not working **

[Link which I am following](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

**Code **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm lang="en">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function()
{
    var availableTags = 
    [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centered">

        <div>
            <label for="tags"> Tags : </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to include all of the links and script in  like below and also in which **order**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/second_page.css" media="all"/>                                                                                                                                                                                     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>                                                                                           <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: you are probably missing jqueryui http://jqueryui.com/download/all/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is the base library for the autocomplete interface. As pointed out, you have to include the UI library layer for your autocomplete in **addition** to the jQuery library. And since you are trying to use the jQuery UI library, you should also add the `stylesheet` required by the jQueryUI library.

In essence, these are the things that you should include on your page:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- jQuery UI CSS

Below is your code modified:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title> Page Title </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <div id="centered">

        <div>
            <label for="tags"> Tags : </label>
            <input id="tags">
        </div>
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


   <!-- your code -->
   <script>
$(function()
{
    var availableTags = 
    [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

include in your html  head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```